# A delay between css animation repetitions

Tags: css, css-animations, infinite

I am trying to create an animation where each letter is moved separately, which works fine but when I add infinite it does not have a delay between the loops so the letters are constantly moving one after another. I tried to add animation delay on the base animation but it just slows down the animation speed.

```css
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh)
    }
}
    
.anim p {
    animation: move 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.anim:nth-child(1) p { animation-delay: 0.5s }
.anim:nth-child(2) p { animation-delay: 1s }
.anim:nth-child(3) p { animation-delay: 1.5s }
.anim:nth-child(4) p { animation-delay: 2s }
```

```html
<div class="anim">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed scelerisque, tellus id cursus interdum, eros mauris bibendum risus, non commodo diam urna et massa.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer gravida vulputate nisl, at ultrices felis convallis vitae. Cras tincidunt lacus eget lectus commodo iaculis. Pellentesque et urna arcu. Integer eu enim a velit sagittis iaculis eu ut nulla.
  </p>
  <p>
    Etiam ac felis id odio dapibus tincidunt id eu mi. Etiam accumsan sagittis ipsum, sed ornare nulla malesuada in. Phasellus gravida risus vel tellus eleifend condimentum. Maecenas sed tellus ipsum. Sed vitae mi ultricies, placerat turpis cursus, accumsan purus. Donec augue tellus, pulvinar vel sapien quis, rhoncus feugiat elit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Nulla non ipsum eleifend turpis interdum euismod. Donec volutpat arcu id sem tristique faucibus. Praesent pulvinar mauris sit amet mi fringilla, a dapibus erat sollicitudin.
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to be infinite with delays between loops after restarts to initial position, currently it directly starts.

Comment: run the code on [link](http://jsfiddle.net) and share the link. So that we will get to know where is the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really need bespoke keyframe animations setting up for each individual item you want to animate - `animation-delay` isn't going to help you here.

I had a play around on codepen and [created a mixin with accompanying functions](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPxBjv?editors=1100) to generate the individual keyframe animations for you.

The mixin is shown below. I haven't included the functions but you will find them on the codepen link.

```
@mixin move($animation-timing, $item-number, $total-items, $delay-between-items) {
    $animation-name: "move" + $item-number;
    $duration: total-time($animation-timing, $total-items, $delay-between-items);
    $start: start-animation($item-number, $delay-between-items, $duration) + 0%;
    $end: end-animation($item-number, $delay-between-items, $duration, $animation-timing) + 0%;

    @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
        #{$start} {
            transform: translateY(0)
        }
        #{$end} {
            transform: translateY(4vh)
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateY(4vh)
        }
    }

    animation: (move + $item-number) ($animation-timing + 0s) ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}
```

You would call the mixin as below.

```
.anim:nth-child(1) p { @include move(0.7, 1, 4, 0.5); }
.anim:nth-child(2) p { @include move(0.7, 2, 4, 0.5); }
.anim:nth-child(3) p { @include move(0.7, 3, 4, 0.5); }
.anim:nth-child(4) p { @include move(0.7, 4, 4, 0.5); }
```

If you can't use SASS / SCSS to generate your bespoke CSS, the compiled CSS from the above code is shown below:

```css
.anim { display: inline-block; }

.anim:nth-child(1) p {
    animation: move1 0.7s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes move1 {
    18.5185185185% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    44.4444444444% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
}

.anim:nth-child(2) p {
    animation: move2 0.7s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes move2 {
    37.037037037% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    62.962962963% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
}

.anim:nth-child(3) p {
    animation: move3 0.7s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes move3 {
    55.5555555556% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    81.4814814815% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
}

.anim:nth-child(4) p {
    animation: move4 0.7s ease-in-out forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes move4 {
    74.0740740741% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(4vh);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim">
    <p>A</p>
</div>
<div class="anim">
    <p>B</p>
</div>
<div class="anim">
    <p>C</p>
</div>
<div class="anim">
    <p>D</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows, i.e. creating the non-active phase by according keyframe states:

```css
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(4vh)
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}
.anim, p {
  display: inline-block;
}
.anim p {
  animation: move 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.anim:nth-child(1) p {
  animation-delay: 0.5s
}

.anim:nth-child(2) p {
  animation-delay: 1s
}

.anim:nth-child(3) p {
  animation-delay: 1.5s
}

.anim:nth-child(4) p {
  animation-delay: 2s
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="anim">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="anim">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="anim">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div class="anim">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your animation run from 0-30% and leave the rest as a "delay" before the animation repeats

check this: https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/