# How to restart group animations in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

How to restart group animations in css?
I need to run them again, applying the delays. Meaning when `zoomersout` is done it will run the `zoomers1` (including the 2s delay) from the start.

I tried to use infinite but what happens is it zooms every 1s. The delay runs once only....

how to make this if possible?

css

```
.letter1{
    color:#74ee76;
    animation: zoomers1 1s ease-in-out forwards,zoomersout 1s ease-in 1s forwards;
}

.letter2{
    color:#7674ee;
    animation: zoomers2 1s ease-in-out 1s forwards,zoomersout 1s ease-in 2s forwards;;
}

@keyframes zoomers1 {
    from {
        z-index: 100;
        scale: 1;
    }

    to {
        font-size:1000px;
        scale: 1;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes zoomers2 {
    from {
        z-index: 200;
        scale: 0;
    }

    to {
        font-size:1000px;
        z-index: 0;
        scale: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes zoomersout {
    from {
        font-size:1000px;
        z-index: 0;
        scale: 1;
    }

    to {
        font-size:1000px;
        z-index: 0;
        scale: 100;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="lett letter1" style="position:absolute" >F</div>
<div class="lett letter2" style="position:absolute" >R</div>
```

example i wish to happen...

```
rerun(){
    run-> animations in letter1 after animations letter2 is done
    run-> animations in letter2 after animations letter1 is done
}
```

Not sure how is this possible in css/javascript/jquery...
Appreciate any solution... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look to this Stack post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052364/a-delay-between-css-animation-repetitions

Comment: How is this related to `javascript` or `jquery`

Comment: Javascript and jquery I think this can be done with them not sure if it works though (delay).

Comment: @LouisGrasset not sure but after the delay it will run the animation base on the duration only and not include delay after the first run.

Comment: On behalf of @thingEvery - what happens if you use jquery/javascript to remove the class and then add it again?

Comment: @freedomn-m tried it using settimeout to add and remove class to run the animation but not working. Would appreciate if you have a working example that uses jquery/javascript.

Comment: hope I was able to answer your question @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `.letter1 animation` style to "none".

Example below :

```
var myelement = document.getElementByClassName("letter1");
myelement.style.animation = "none";
myelement.style.offsetHeight; //now set offset
```

Comment: how will it run again if there's no more animation?